# How would I see a list of current packages and compare them to the ones being upgraded?

Tags: 12.10, server, updates, webserver, aptitude

I'm running 12.10 on a server and I have a list of packages that need to be upgraded. However I can run the command `sudo aptitude` to see what they are and what their about which is fine. My question is, "Is there a way to see the current ones installed compared to the ones I am about to install?"

That is, can I compare the packages before saying, "Yes, take this one" or "No, don't take that one"? Also how do you say "No, don't take that one"? (sort of like cherry picking which updates I want)

Comment: You can select which updates you want through the update manager.  Don't know about comparing though.

Comment: this is all through command line